# SQL: How do I combine similar value rows into one, not affecting the rest

Tags: sql, join, merge, ssms

Is there a way to merge similar values in the same column and not affect the rest, for example:
[image: 1]

I want to sum Amount by Company and ID too.

Comment: you cannot do this way, in the sql layer. you need to do this at the presenation layer. In SQL layer, the company name will repeat for the rows

Comment: then, how do I sum? Because when I type
SELECT [Company], [ID], SUM([Amount]) AS [AMOUNT]
FROM #temptable

it shows me this error: invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You need to have GROUP BY clause for aggregation. See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get the data you want to display. You will be getting company name being repeated. If you want to dispaly data in the way, where company name is not repeating for subsequent rows, you have to use EXCEL or some other presentation layer tool.

```sql
SELECT Company, ID, SUM(Amount)
FROM Table1
GROUP BY Company,ID
```

```
+---------+-----+--------+
| Company | ID  | Amount |
+---------+-----+--------+
| ABC     | 001 |      3 |
| ABC     | 002 |      3 |
| DEF     | 002 |     10 |
| DEF     | 003 |      5 |
+---------+-----+--------+
```